# Dynamic POST key in jQuery data

Tags: jquery

```
var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
var typeId = $(this).attr("data-value");

if(type=="category") var typeVar="cat";
else if(type=="subcategory") var typeVar="subcat";

$.ajax({
    url: 'admin-catalog/next',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {typeVar: typeId, limit: 9},
    success: newGalleryProducts
});
```

The key 'typeVar' in my 'data' key needs to be dynamic, i.e. it should not post 'typeVar' as the key, it should post either 'cat' or 'subcat'.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
var typeId = $(this).attr("data-value");

if(type=="category") var typeVar="cat";
else if(type=="subcategory") var typeVar="subcat";

var post_data = {};
post_data[typeVar] = typeId;
post_data['limit'] = 9;

$.ajax({
    url: 'admin-catalog/next',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: post_data,
    success: newGalleryProducts
});
```

If you want to do it within the `data` key, you can do such way:

```
data: function(){var o = {}; o[typeVar] = typeId; o['limit'] = 9;return o;}(),
```

Or like @archil metioned, use `JSON.parse` method:

```
data: JSON.parse('{ "' + typeVar + '": "' + typeId + '", "limit": "9"}'),
```

Comment: Cheers. So there is no way to do it within the 'data' key?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve that by using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.C2.A0strings)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'admin-catalog/next',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.Parse('{ "' + typeVar + '": "' + typeId + '", "limit": "9"}'),
    success: newGalleryProducts
});
```